# How can I reshape this 1d array to have another one with commas?

Tags: python

Currently:

```
[10.43067171 10.54604655 11.01525192 10.72681761 10.86467023 10.40567241
 10.03239009  8.76512298  8.80803634  7.96358238  6.84964989  6.06443495]
```

Aiming:

```
[10.43067171,10.54604655,11.01525192,10.72681761,10.86467023,10.40567241,
 10.03239009,8.76512298,8.80803634,7.96358238,6.84964989,6.06443495]
```

This to be able to plot it.

Comment: This doesn't really make sense. Are you using numpy? Numpy just prints without commas, that doesn't mean anything about the shape of the underlying ndarray.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is not clear in your question what is the type of the first list , currently it is not a valid variable, the only way for this to work the first variable should be a string, assuming that you can try the below solution

```
>>> x = ["10.43067171 10.54604655 11.01525192"]
>>> y = x[0].split(" ")
>>> y
['10.43067171', '10.54604655', '11.01525192']
>>> z = [float(x) for x in y]
>>> z
[10.43067171, 10.54604655, 11.01525192]
```